# How to get the value of a value passed by reference in C++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I have a function with the following declaration:

```
void cleanValid(int valid[][4], int &size, int index);
```

In implementation of this function I need to set another counter equal to the integer size passed by reference. I tried doing something like:

```
int count;
count = size;
```

If I'm not mistaken, when I change the value of count it will change the value of size as well. I can't have this happen though. How would I go about copying the value of size into count and keeping them independent?

Comment: Additionally, it would be better to write `int count = size;`, uninitialized variables are a nightmare and your compiler should provide a warning if you activate them all. If you want a broader scope, use a magic value for initialization `int count = 0;` for example, but don't let it at an undefined value (c++ does not guarantee that built-in will be initialized, though in debug mode some compilers will do it nonetheless such as VC++).

Comment: IMO it is better to leave the value uninitialised, than to use a magic initialisation value. If you accidentally end up using an uninitialised variable, there is a reasonable chance of a compiler warning. If you accidentally use a meaningless value, your code won't do what it is supposed to, and you certainly will not get any warnings. Explicit initialisation with 0 should be saved for situations where 0 means something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you've got it wrong. When you read from the reference into a non-reference variable, you're not setting up any kind of linkage between the two. You will have an independent copy of the value of `size` at that time, nothing else.

If you *wanted* to affect the value of `size`, you would have to use a reference to it:

```
int& count = size;

/* ... */    
count= 32;  /* This will change size, too. */
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want `size` to change, why not pass by value/const reference?

```
void cleanValid(int valid[][4], int size, int index);
```

or

```
void cleanValid(int valid[][4], const int &size, int index);
```

in both options you **ensure** `size` is not changed - by letting the compiler take care of it.

Comment: Plus, in the first example you have the advantage of being able to use size directly. You can do whatever you want with it, and you don't need to copy it again into a local variable. Also, in some cases an int is smaller than a reference, so there can be less to copy.

Answer (score 2):

`int count = size` *copies* the value of size into count. If you change count since you are modifying a copy, size will remain unaffected.